# Size of UTF string

Tags: utf

If I have a string in UTF-16 with values "hello", and If I write it to a file, what will be the size of the file?  will it be 5 bytes or 10 bytes or 13 bytes(with BOM) ?

Answer (score 0):

The file will be 10 bytes long or 12 bytes with a BOM.

Writing a string "hello" implies 5 or 6 characters `'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' '\0'` depending on the writing method used.  Let's assume the `'\0'` byte is not written. The optional BOM is another "character".  As you are not writing any character with a Unicode value >= `0x10000`, each character will take up 2 bytes in the file.

Note: Had the string been written using UTF8 encoding, the file length would have been 5 (or 8 with BOM).